# How to stop an infinite loop in javascript when using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, react-state

I'm mapping through an array of items to generate images, but each time it sends my code into an infinite loop. Here's my code:

This is the mapping code:

```
let mySrc = this.state.imageUrl;

{myImages.map(image => {
       this.getSrc(userId, image.id); 

       return(
       <img src={mySrc}/>)
    })}
```

This is the "getSrc" function:

```
getSrc = async (userId, image) => {
    axios
      .get(`http://mysiteeee.com/api/getimage/${userId}/photo/${image}`, {
           auth: {
              username: 'username',
              password: 'password'
              },
              responseType: 'blob'
            })
      .then(res => {
          let myUrl = URL.createObjectURL(res.data)
          console.log(myUrl)
          this.setState({
              imageUrl: myUrl
              })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Whenever I go to the page, it shuffles through all the image URLs / images over and over forever. How do I only show the image URLs / images once? How do I stop shuffling through images infinitely?

Here's the entire component's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import HeaderTwo from './HeaderTwo';


class FullDescription extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            eventInfo: [],
            imageUrl: [],
            clicked: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);

        this.props.state.images.map(image => 
            this.getSrc(this.props.state.id, image.id))

        // this.getSrc(this.props.state.id, this.props.state.images[1].id)
    }

    changeClicked = (userId) => {
        if(this.state.clicked === false){
            this.setState({
                clicked: true
            }) 
        } else {
            this.setState({
                clicked: false
            })
        }
    }

    getSrc = async (userId, image) => {
        axios
            .get(`http://http://mysiteeee.com/api/getimage/${userId}/photo/${image}`, {
                auth: {
                    username: 'username',
                    password: 'password'
                    },
                    responseType: 'blob'
            })
            .then(res => {
                let myUrl = URL.createObjectURL(res.data)
                this.state.imageUrl.push(myUrl)

                // this.setState({
                //     imageUrl: myUrl
                //     })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    } 

    render() {
        let item = this.props.state;
        let date = new Date(item.date).toDateString();
        let time = new Date(item.date).toLocaleTimeString();
        let userId = this.props.state.id;
        let myImages = this.state.imageUrl;
        let checkMark = <button className='attend-button' onClick={() => this.changeClicked(userId)}>Attend Event</button>;

        console.log(myImages)

        if(this.state.clicked === true){
            checkMark = <button className='attend-button' onClick={() => this.changeClicked(userId)}>&#x2713; Attend Event</button>
        } else {
            checkMark = <button className='attend-button' onClick={() => this.changeClicked(userId)}>Attend Event</button>
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <HeaderTwo/>
                <body id="full-description-page">
                <div className='images-section'>
                    {myImages.map(mySrc => <img src={mySrc}/>)}
                </div>
                    <div id='heading-strip'>
                        <img src={myImages} className='heading-image'/>
                        <div className='heading-info'>
                            <p className='date'>{date}<br/>{time}</p>
                            <p className='name'>{item.name}</p>
                            <p className='location'><b>Location:</b> <br/>{item.location.name}, {item.location.address}, {item.location.city}, {item.location.state}</p>
                            <div className='button-area'>
                                    {checkMark}
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br/>
                    <p className='description'><b>Description:</b> {item.description}</p>


                    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <p className='comments-header'><b>Comments:</b></p>
                    <div className='comments-section'>
                        {item.comments.map(comment =>
                            <div className='comments'>
                                <p>{comment.text}<br/><b>-{comment.from}</b></p>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </body>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FullDescription;
```

Comment: I noticed some things that you can inspect, to help you find what is causing the infinite loop, 

* Is `myImages` a state value that is being set on then? 
* Are you returning the axios get in getSrc function? 
* Also try to inspect that `setState` you are doing on `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the code is that you are calling `getSrc` method inside the render method and `updating the state`.

> Whenever there is a change in state, React will call the render method.

In this case React call the render method and in the render method there is a state update, hence React call the render method again, and this process goes on forever.

**Solution.**

Remove the `this.getSrc` from render method and call the `getSrc` method in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

I made a small change in the map function as well.

Example.

```
let myImages = this.state.imageUrl;

{myImages.map(mySrc => <img src={mySrc}/>)}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.getSrc();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked to stop the infinite loop. I'm trying to get every photo to show now. I changed imageUrl to an array to push all of the links into the imageUrl array. Do you know how I would map through the array of links to render all of the images on the page? This issue is the links don't have a property key associated with them, just indexes. Would I need to do a for loop?

Comment: `map` function is used to iterate over array, If you have image links in the imageUrl array, then my current snipped of the render code will work.

Comment: I don't know why, but now none of the images will show. When I just have a single url string in the imageUrl, it will render the single image. But if I have an array of images in the imageUrl and map over the array, none of the images appear.

Comment: In the componentDidMount. I have console.logs that show it's not empty. I can see the urls. They just aren't rendering on the page.

Comment: Should I be pushing the url like this in the function: this.state.imageUrl.push(myUrl). Or is there a way to push the links in this.setState that I should do instead?

Comment: ```[]
0: "blob:http://localhost:3000/30f58481-36bd-4240-9b97-f1729086e48f"
1: "blob:http://localhost:3000/e982c3db-9581-4e96-a2b2-93c705bd580f"
2: "blob:http://localhost:3000/6b2d7b6b-8040-43dc-8a75-56cee162a5f3"
3: "blob:http://localhost:3000/19f810eb-8261-4166-9fba-a246e43cd02a"
4: "blob:http://localhost:3000/4771ff5f-dfe6-4d55-b7b0-e8866e1366ff"
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)```

Comment: Yes I am using that

Comment: I just updated the question. The url is not a real url in the axios get request.

Comment: You are mutating the state, don't mutate the state. update the state like `this.setState(preState =>{
                    imageUrl: myUrl
                })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206290/discussion-between-sohail-and-page-cow).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are changing the state with :

```
   this.setState({
      imageUrl: myUrl
   })
```

and at the same time you use `this.state.imageUrl` inside your render function, makes it loop continuously, because every time it renders, it starts again to do the array.map and the array.map call will trigger a new state update... so it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

Also i think you might need to use map likke this

```
{myImages.map(image => {
   this.getSrc(image.userId, image.image.id); 

   return(
   <img src={mySrc}/>)
})}
```